# javascript (Testing objects for properties)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Was working on this, just wondering what `checkProp` meant? Where did the checkProp argument came from?

```js
// Setup
var myObj = {
  gift: "pony",
  pet: "kitten",
  bed: "sleigh"
};

function checkObj(checkProp) {
  // Your Code Here
  var result = myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp);

  if (result == true) {
    return myObj[checkProp];
  } else {
    return "Not Found";
  }


}

// Test your code by modifying these values
checkObj("gift");
```

Comment: The definition for the function `checkObj()` is `function checkObj(checkProp){}` where `checkProp` is a parameter (or input) to `checkObj()`, so `checkobj("gift")` is supplying `"gift"` to the function, and that is where `checkProp` comes from. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: This is a really basic programming question. You need to learn how functions work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change code below this line

  var myObj = {
    gift: "pony",
    pet: "kitten",
    bed: "sleigh",
    city: "Seattle"
  };

  return (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) ? myObj[checkProp] : "Not Found";

  // Only change code above this line
}
```

To interpret the solution, please have some patience & go though the explanation.

o According to the question and the instructions that are been provided to solve the problem, we first need to create an object and define its properties along with the values provided.

o Now, understanding the code:

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
```

The function named `checkObj` has parameters `obj` (which will take its input form the object `myObj` that we created) & `checkProp` (this will take input as the properties of the object).

o Inside the function:

```
    var myObj = {
    gift: "pony",
    pet: "kitten",
    bed: "sleigh",
    city: "Seattle"
  };
```

Here we defined the object `myObj` (self declared, according to the need) with its properties.

o **Now comes the most interesting part of the code** (for which I spent almost my day to figure out how can I find a solution to this, in spite of surfing through various cool sites but couldn't be any satisfied), here we go:

```
return (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) ? myObj[checkProp] : "Not Found";
```

Since we have created a function, that means some value needs to be returned in order to make its use, for that we will use `return`.
Now, using [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) we need to check if the required property in the object is found or not.

o The method we used here, [.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
(obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp))
```

contains the `obj` parameter of the function, which will store the object `myObj` that we created.
And now, as this `obj` has stored the entire object, we can now check if this object has the specific property or not for which we used here `.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)` this method, wherein this `propertyName` should get replaced with checkProp, because in the `checkObj` function, `checkProp` is the parameter which has stored the parameters of the object.

- So in a way, `obj` corresponds to `myobj` & `checkProp` corresponds to the object's properties.

o Now,

```
? myObj[checkProp] : "Not Found"; 
}
```

This is the remaining part of the code which will be checked against its counterpart, just to make sure if the condition is "true" or "false".
Here, `myObj` will now access the properties that are been held by the parameter `checkProp`.
So if the conditional check is successful, that means the property is found and it will return that property's value otherwise, `"Not Found"` should get returned.

**As I am in beginner stage, so if there is anything which is missing or explained wrongly, please do share your thoughts, that would be helpful to all of us..!!!**

Answer (score 2):

that was my answer in freecodecamp (Testing Objects for Properties):

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)==true){
    return obj[checkProp];
  }else
  return "Not Found";
  obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp);
  return "Change Me!";
}
```

Comment: That is really not the question. Question is a basic question about how argument passing match with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be:

```
function checkObj(checkProp) {
  // Your Code Here
 if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
    return myObj[checkProp];
  }
  return "Not Found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checkProp is a function argument.

```
checkObj('gift')
```

In this case:

```
checkProp = 'gift'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change code below this line
 var myObj = {
   gift: "pony",
   pet: "kitten",
   bed: "sleigh",
   city: "Seattle",
   };
   
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)){
     return obj[checkProp];
   }else {
     return "Not Found";
   }
  
   // Only change code above this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trepidation and anxiety are the basic bugs you'll introduce when dealing with simple scenarios like this. Below are two methods that'll be greatly helpful:
Method 1 (Using if else statement):
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {

```
 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {

     return obj[checkProp];
    }
      else {
        return "Not Found";
    }
}
    //Method 2 (Using switch statement):

    switch (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
    case true:
       return obj[checkProp];
       break;
       default:
       return "Not Found";
    }
```

The expression is a template that should check a seeming array of properties with any variable inserted, which needs no initial declaration or assignments. Defining the function, conditioning it and applying correct logic or algorithm is pivotal to its correctness.

1. After defining the function:
   function checkObj(obj, checkObj) {
   }

- with obj and checkObj representing the object, and property respectively,

2. You'll proceed to stating the condition that validates the preciseness of your function: using the 'if else' to select the object (obj) in the array and then scan around for the presence of the said property (checkProp).
3. Lastly, you'll return the value, ending your loop with an alternative value if the statement is not true.

With this, I believe you can understand the second procedure as well - the switch, case and break. I hope you find value.

Answer (score 0):

The hasOwnProperty(propertyName) method is used to determine if the property of a given object exists, and returns true or false based on whether or not the porperty was found.An object holds a key/value pair, which makes it simpler for us to search for an object property, instead of using a switch or IF statement.

The below code worked for me:

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  const wishList = {
    "gift" : "pony",
    "pet" : "kitten",
    "bed" : "sleigh",
    "city" : "Seattle"
  }

  if(! obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)){
    return "Not Found"
  }else{
    return obj[checkProp];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Setup
var myObj = {
  gift: "pony",
  pet: "kitten",
  bed: "sleigh"
};

function checkObj(myObj,checkProp) {
  // Your Code Here
  var result = myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp);
  if (result == true) {
    return myObj[checkProp];
  } 
 else {
    return "Not Found";
  }
}

// Test your code by modifying these values

checkObj("gift");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
    return obj[checkProp]
  } else {
    return "Not Found"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. If I am not on point then I am sorry.
Here it is clear cut that they want to teach you how to use "**hasOwnProperty**" and we can directly use it inside the code.
***It returns a boolean** and we can use it to directly achieve the output which we wanted in the original case*.

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change the code below this line

  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)){
    return "Not Found"
  }else{
    return obj[checkProp];
  }
  // Only change the code above this line
}
```

We can rewrite the code above as a one-liner.
It is in the following fashion-
(condition)? work to do if the situation was true: work to do if the state was false ;
**Please remember to add ":" and "?" in mid to separate data**

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change the code below this line

  return (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) ? obj[checkProp] : "Not Found";

  // Only change the code above this line
}
```

Please feel free to add or ask anything and I will be trying my best to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
    return obj[checkProp];
  }
  else if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp) && !(checkProp.length === 0)) {
    return "Not Found";
  }
  return "Change Me!";
  // Only change code above this line
}

console.log(checkObj({gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh"}, "gift"));
```

Answer (score -1):

checkProp is the placeholder for first argument which you pass to the function checkObj. You can have any name (e.g abc,def etc) instead of checkProp.